# Image not showing with the Path. I want to show images dynamically based on path coming from the database

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js

[image: The view shows the path but not the images.]

Below is the HTML code for displaying the image. I have also used require.

```
       <div class="label-text" v-for="(imageLinks, index) in urlLinks" :key="index" >
            <img   :src="{imageLinks}" alt="SomeWords">
            <p>{{imageLinks}}</p>         
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `:src="imageLinks"` not `:src="{imageLinks}"`

```
<div class="label-text" v-for="(imageLinks, index) in urlLinks" :key="index" >
    <img :src="imageLinks" alt="SomeWords">
    <p>{{imageLinks}}</p>         
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Nitheesh! still the same result.

Comment: Is the path to the image correct?

Comment: You are displaying the image link using `<p>{{imageLinks}}</p>` just below the image. Try to create a image tag with the url avalable in the screen like `<img src="../the/long/path/you/are/seeing/in/screen" />` and check whether it works. If its not working, then defenitely its a path issue.

Comment: Hi Nitheesh! Maybe the path was wrong but I used our server location with http address link and it works like a charm. Thank you for your effort.